# Using different Stylebooks for different organizations/user groups in Liferay

Tags: liferay, portal, liferay-theme

I'm using Liferay 7.4 to renew our university portal.
For the different areas of studies we use different colors, so I made a stylebook for each area.
How can I assign the stylebooks to organizations or user groups?

I found a similar question for Liferay 6.2, but the link in the post isn't working anymore:
[different Style for Users with different Roles in Liferay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024145/different-style-for-users-with-different-roles-in-liferay)
Is it still possible in 7.4? If not, is there any other option?

Comment: Stylebooks never worked in 6.2, as they were only introduced in 7.3 - that being said, without custom development you can apply them to sites, but not to users. As this questiion is not about programming as defined in [help/on-topic], I'd suggest to carry this over to the liferay community on https://liferay.dev/